# Flat PointCloud with Turtlebot simulated kinect

Tags: gazebo, kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to acquire the point cloud from the simulated kinect in the Turtlebot.
However, when I try to visualize the point cloud with rviz, the point cloud looks "flat", as if (almost) all the points got projected on a plane. On the right you can see a (small) image representing what the world actually is.

[image description http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg205/scaled.php?server=205&filename=senzatitolony.png&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg205/scaled.php?server=205&filename=senzatitolony.png&res=landing)

I just followed the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Map%20in%20TurtleBot%20Simulator) to simulate the turtlebot.

Anyone else faced a similar issue? Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36801/flat-pointcloud-with-turtlebot-simulated-kinect/) by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) on 2012-07-03**:
I am having exactly the same problem, and cannot figure out what is wrong. Some other answers say that it could be a problem of graphic card, which one are you using ?

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-07-03**:
@Yannis I tried first on a computer with nvidia geforce gt 520mx + intel graphic card integrated. Then I managed to make it work on a little bit older computer with nvidia geforce 200M. I installed drivers 295.53 (there were problems in installing the latest version).

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-07-03**:
@Yannis I tried also on a MacBookPro, launching Ubuntu on VMWare, but same problems. Actually I'm not 100% sure the problem is the graphic card (it means I don't know, not I don't think so), but once I got a working solution I didn't touch anything else for fear of crushing up everything :)

**Comment by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) on 2012-07-04**:
Ok, so it worked with the two Nvidia graphic card right ? I think I'll buy one, because I tried on a desktop that had integrated graphics and I got the same problem.

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-07-04**:
@Yannis Yes, but it worked with the nvidia geforce 200M, which is pretty old. It didn't with the nvidia geforce gt 520mx...I would suggest you to be sure before buying a graphic card, otherwise you may just waste money :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the same problem as mentioned in this thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/12150/problem-simulating-kinect-in-gazebo/

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0